# Permutations with Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

I am currently writing a grammar that needs to recognize the
strings abc, acb, bac, bca etc. All Permutations of "abc".

Am I just missing something, or would I have to write all possible combinations like:
S -> abc | acb | ... 
to achieve full coverage.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to recognize each possible ordering independently. There's no short-cut with standard BNF notation. With regular expressions you can factor to reduce the length of the regular expression a bit, but it won't help you much. (For example, if you wanted all combinations of `a`,`b`,`c` and `d`, you could write `(ab|ba)(cd|dc)` instead of the slight longer `abcd|abdc|bacd|badc`, but it won't help too much.

For three or four elements that's not too bad, but it doesn't scale. The usual solution is to allow any sequence of the elements, and check for duplicates either at the end or as you go, depending on the capabilities of the parser generator you're using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I figured. Unfortunately I have to be very careful not to overgenerate too much for the problem I'm working with, since I have too keep the total amount of valid strings as low as possible, so I guess I just have to deal with the longer version